# Why did they arrange things like this beside the pool?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-follows

Near the finale of [It Follows (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Follows), when they try to trap It in a public swimming pool, they arranged various things beside the pool, like shown in this picture:

[image]

Why did they arrange those things in this way beside the pool?

Comment: Er, notice how they're all electrical appliances that are plugged in...?

Comment: @ what for I am asking.

Comment: To electrocute 'It' when it comes close. Isn't this explained in the movie? (I forget.)

Comment: It was suppose dot be used as weapon against that thing to electrocute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

‘It Follows’ Director Explains Unconventional Finale

[Vulture](http://www.vulture.com/2015/03/it-follows-director-the-spoiler-interview.html)/ [Bloody-disgusting](http://bloody-disgusting.com/news/3337903/it-follows-director-explains-unconventional-finale/)

> Mitchell speaks to Vulture about the final sequence in which the kids
>   surround a pool with electrical devices in hopes of electrocuting? the
>   creature. It’s a really stupid plan, but Mitchell’s reasoning behind
>   it is completely sound.
>
> “It’s the stupidest plan ever! [Laughs.] It’s a kid-movie plan, it’s
>   something that Scooby-Doo and the gang might think of, and that was
>   sort of the point. What would you do if you were confronted by a
>   monster and found yourself trapped within a nightmare? Ultimately, you
>   have to resort to some way of fighting it that’s accessible to you in
>   the physical world, and that’s not really going to cut it. We kind of
>   avoid any kind of traditional setup for that sequence, because in more
>   traditional horror films, there might be a clue that would lead them
>   to figure out a way to destroy this monster. I intentionally avoided
>   placing those. Instead, they do their best to accomplish something,
>   and we witness its failure. It’s probably a very non-conventional way
>   of approaching the third-act confrontation, but we thought it was a
>   fun way to deal with it.

Comment: Is there any way to summarize the essence of the answer a little to make this more than a plain big quote block?